# Only shows one row when making another query inside of a query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a friendlist on my website, and I've stored the usernames inside the database and not their full names.
So I'd just make another query inside the friendlist...

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username = $r['username'];
    // Wanna find the real name
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $fullname = $row['fullname'];
    echo $fullname;
}
```

It works fine, but it only displays one row, and not all rows.
When I just display the username, it shows all the rows.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a weak, high-speed hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: This is not the code that I use in my program, it was just an example of what was happening. And I use "password_hash()" for the users and not MD5 or SHA1, but it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Home-rolled security systems usually do little to keep determined attackers out. Don't roll your own if security is of any concern at all, which it should be if you're dealing with actual users.

Comment: If you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `username`, which is a normal thing to do, then this should return one row and one row only. If all you need is `fullname`, then select just that. If you want all rows, remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: But the friends is saved in a database, where there is the username of the two friends, and not the full name. So i go to the users database, to pick the full names

Comment: Just do no reassign `$result` inside the loop and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You re-use the `$result` used from your original query...

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username = $r['username'];
    // Wanna find the real name
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    $fullname = $row['fullname'];
    echo $fullname;
}
```

I've just changed the inner query to use `$result1`

You should also look into prepared statements and not inline your field values.

Answer (score 1):

There's a multitude of problems here, but it boils down to doing a so-called *N+1* query. You do one query to fetch *N* rows, and then you make *N* more queries, one for each row, to retrieve additional details.

You can do that all in one shot with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT x, users.username FROM y WHERE (x conditions)
  LEFT JOIN users ON users.username=y.username
```

That way you can grab all that data at once. It's worth noting that using `username` as a key like this is often severely problematic as you'll either need to layer in a whole bunch of cascading trigger conditions to track referential integrity, or you won't have any referential integrity at all. Try and use numerical values as primary keys within your database, and use things like `username` only as labels for humans.

The risk here is if someone deletes their account and another person creates an account with exactly the same name, they "inherit" those friends from the former person. This has shown up on big sites and caused tons of trouble where people effectively gain ownership of content someone else has abandoned.